# C# initialized object values

Tags: c#, object, initialization

Is there a way to change C# object values all at once...in one line?

So if I have a class `Result` with `string msg` and `bool isPositive` and I already call the constructor somewhere before like `var result = new Result();` can I change values somehow by not entering:

```
result.msg = "xxxxxx";
result.bool = false;
```

But doing something like what you can do while instantiating:

```
result { msg = "", bool = true}
```

I know I can do it by instantiating again a new object by:

```
var result = new Result() { msg = "", bool = true}
```

but that is not my question :)

Comment: No, there is not.  It is a GOOD thing that you can't do this, since it hurts readability and maintainability which should always be your first concern.

Comment: You do know that the initialization syntax just compiles down to basically the same thing with just a temporary value

Comment: VB.Net has `with` which is similarish, there is no equivalence in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you create a method that do that for you...

```
public void SetResult(string msg, bool flag)
{
   myFlag = flag;
   myMsg = msg;

}
```

and then you invoke it:

```
 myResult.SetResult("xxx", false);  // one line
```

Comment: Too bad C# doesn't have the feature I want, but nice workaround

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function to reset values. For example:

```
public class Result
{
    ...
    public void ResetResult()
    {
        msg = "xxxxxx";
        boole = false;
    }

}
```

Then, to perform your reset,

```
var result = new Result() { msg = "", boole = true}
//...Do whatever you want to do with result.
result.ResetResult();
//...Do whatever you want to do with the *reset* result.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a setter:

```
class Result
{
    public string msg;
    public bool boolean;

    public SetValues(string message, bool boolean)
    {
         msg = message;
         this.boolean = boolean;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
SetValues("a string", true);
```

You can also take advantage of the optional parameters:

```
public SetValues(string message = "", bool boolean = false)
{
     msg = message;
     this.boolean = boolean;
}
```

So you can call the method without specify any parameter, and it will work as a reset:

```
SetValues();
```

But I will still recommend to use initialization list, as making a setter which sets multiple properties is not really a good practice since you can set each one of them in various ways, and still it violates a bit the [SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542051/learning-single-responsibility-principle-with-c-sharp).

Comment: Isn't this just the same as @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ's answer?

Comment: public bool bool; does this even compile in your pc?

Comment: @GeoffJames I was writing when he posted it. Also this answer contains the definition of the method, instead of an empty one, but it's the same principle

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ of course it does not, I have just changed it. I was wondering too if it will compile :D

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly you could implement a method within your class that does what you need, for example:

```
public class Result
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; } 
        public int Property2 { get; set; }

        //directly in the instatation of the object
        public Result()
        {
            this.Property1 = "a";
            this.Property2 = 1;
        }

        //or explicitely within a method
        public void ChangeValues()
        {
            this.Property1 = "a";
            this.Property2 = 1;
        }

        //or explicitely setting the values from outside as parameters
        public void ChangeValues(string property1, int property2)
        {
            this.Property1 = property1;
            this.Property2 = property2;
        }

    }
```

Ussage:

```
//option 1 
var result = new Result(); //values would be already set here 

//option 2
var result = new Result();
result.ChangeValues(); //values would be set here 

//option 3
var result = new Result();
result.ChangeValues("a",1);
```

You could also iterate thru the properties in order to set each one with different values, but that would be a bit of overkill I think

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is very similar - (almost the same) *almost* - as the other answers here.

I thought I'd provide a little different take on the other answers - just offering an alternative way of using a `public` method to call...

---

You could define the "default" values of the properties within the `Result` class, by using `const`ants (or even just normal fields).

Then, set the properties' default values to those constants (or fields, whichever).

Then, when you construct a new `Result()` with no Initializer, the `Result` object is created with those defaults.

You can then use a `Reset()` function that also uses these default values.

This can prove a little easier to maintain when it comes to refactoring, too.

---

Here's how you could define your `Result` class's properties and method:

```
public class Result
{
    private const string defaultMsg = "xxx";
    private const bool defaultIsPositive = false;

    public string Msg { get; set; } = defaultMsg;
    public bool IsPositive { get; set; } = defaultIsPositive;

    public void Reset()
    {
        Msg = defaultMsg;
        IsPositive = defaultIsPositive;
    }
}
```

Note that the `public string Msg { get; set; } = defaultMsg;` is a nice short-hand way of initializing the property (I think it's only available from C#6.0).

Another way could be to do this through the constructor, like so:

```
public Result()
{
    Msg = defaultMsg;
    IsPositive = defaultIsPositive;
}
```

---

Then, to consume it's as easy as creating the object, doing whatever with it; and then calling the `Reset()` method:

```
// create a Result object with its default values
var result = new Result();

// OR

// create a Result object with some non-default values
var result = new Result { Msg = "something", IsPositive = true };
```

Then, manipulate or do what you will, with your `result` object.

Then, to reset the values:

```
... // do whatever with your result object

// reset the result to its default values
result.Reset();
```