# Where instance should be created in web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

In web api controller, I used to create instance within `using keyword` so Once it come out from the using, `GC` will be called and memory will be released.

The code which I'm using right now,

```
public class TemplateController : AutoVHCBaseApiController
    {

        [Route("{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(VHC.Core.Common.Beans.CheckTemplate))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using(ITemplateManager manager=new   TemplateManager())
                {
                    CheckTemplate checkTemplate = manager.GetCheckTemplate(id, SiteCode);
                    return Ok(checkTemplate);
                }
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message, FailureReason.ReasonCodeOptions.ValidationError);
            }
        }
    }
```

One of my collegue asked me to modify like below:

```
public class TemplateController : AutoVHCBaseApiController
    {
        private readonly ITemplateManager manager;
        public TemplateController()
        {
            manager = new TemplateManager();
        }

        [Route("{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(VHC.Core.Common.Beans.CheckTemplate))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                CheckTemplate checkTemplate = manager.GetCheckTemplate(id, SiteCode);
                return Ok(checkTemplate);
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message, FailureReason.ReasonCodeOptions.ValidationError);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why should i have to create a instance at constuctor?
What is the difference of the both code to creating instance?

Answer (score 3):

The first code is tightly coupled which means [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien): you can't unit test your action because it is dependent on the concrete `TemplateManager`.

The second code is a bit better because the action is not [responsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542051/learning-single-responsibility-principle-with-c-sharp) for creating the concrete `TemplateManager` but it is still tightly coupled because the class is still responsible for the creation.

A better solution is to use an IOC container to handle dependency injection project wide. eg. [Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595472/mvc5-web-api-2-and-ninject) also handles [IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234802/guidelines-for-dispose-and-ninject) so you don't have to call `Dispose()` yourself.

```
private readonly ITemplateManager _manager;
public TemplateController(ITemplateManager manager)
{
    _manager = manager;
}
```

This way you can unit test your `Get` action by mocking the behaviour of `ITemplateManager manager` while not depending on the concrete `TemplateManager`.

Comment: I agreed with Petre - DJ (dependency injection) is the best way to do this.