# How to make an aggregate View Model in MVVM?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

How to make an aggregate View Model in MVVM? basically I wanna add multiple ViewModels together. Here is what I have tried.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace NavigationAssistant
{
    internal class NavigationAssistantViewModel
    {
        private IVsUIShell uiShell;

        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; }

        public NavigationAssistantViewModel(IVsUIShell uiShell, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.uiShell = uiShell;
            this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        private ICommand changeThemeCommand;

        public ICommand ChangeThemeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return this.changeThemeCommand ?? (this.changeThemeCommand = new VSCommand(this._serviceProvider, this.uiShell));
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, what I've done in the past one of two things.

1. Refactor each into separate MVVM classes to respect [Single Responsibilty Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542051/learning-single-responsibility-principle-with-c-sharp).
2. Create one MVVM class that houses pertinent classes.

   ```
   internal class WrapperViewModel
   {
       private IVsUIShell uiShell;
       private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; }

       public WrapperViewModel(IVsUIShell uiShell, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
       }        

       //multiple classes
       public NavigationAssistantViewModel NavigationAssistantViewModel { get;set;}
       public MvvmClass2 MvvmClass2 { get;set;}
   }

   //multiple classes      
   private class NavigationAssistantViewModel {

   }

   private class MvvmClass2 {

   }
   ```

Is this helpful?  If not could you clarify your question?