# How single responsibility principle avoid code smell in this scenario?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I'm new to Design Patterns, I know the purpose of single responsibility principle, but not 100% sure how it can avoid  lots of tiny changes. Below is my example:

```
//very crude implementation
public class Journal
{
    private readonly List<string> entries = new List<string>();
    private static int count = 0;

    public void AddEntry(string text)
    {
       entries.Add($"{++count}: {text}");
    }

    public void RemoveEntry(int index)
    {
       entries.RemoveAt(index);
       count--;
    }

    public void SaveToDisk(string filename)
    {
       File.WriteAllText(filename, ToString());
    }
}
```

I know the `SaveToDisk` method should not be included in the class, it should be a dedicated class, like `PersistenceManager` to handle the file saving.

But why can't I keep the `SaveToDisk()` method in `Journal` class? if there is any new requirements such as Save the Journal to cloud, then I just add a new method `SaveToCloud()`, and any dependent client classes can use `SaveToCloud()`, the only modification I need to make is adding `SaveToCloud()` in `Journal` class, which is totally fine?

**Edited: below is my modified version, please spot any design errors:**

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Consumer client = new Consumer(new DiskManager("C:\\journal.txt"));
    // consumer add text to Journal
    client.AddJournal("sometext");
    client.SaveJournal();
  }
}

public class Journal
{
  private readonly List<string> entries = new List<string>();

  public void AddEntry(string text)
  {
    entries.Add(text);
  }

  public void RemoveEntry(int index)
  {
    entries.RemoveAt(index);
  }
}

public interface IPersistenceManager
{
  void Save(Journal journal);
}

public class DiskManager : IPersistenceManager
{
  private string filePath;

  public DiskManager(string filePath)
  {
    this.filePath = filePath;
  }

  public void Save(Journal journal)
  {
    //XXX.XXX.Save(filePath);
  }
}

public class CloudManager : IPersistenceManager
{
  private string url;

  public CloudManager(string url)
  {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public void Save(Journal journal)
  {
    //XXX.XXX.Save(url);
  }
}


public class Consumer
{
  private Journal _journal = new Journal();
  private IPersistenceManager _manager;

  public void AddJournal(string note)
  {
    _journal.AddEntry(note);
  }

  public Consumer(IPersistenceManager manager)
  {
    _manager = manager;
  }
  public void SaveJournal()
  {
    _manager.Save(_journal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing this, I have a question: how do you load a journal? Probably from outside the journal class, right?

Comment: @John to keep things easy, let's say I just need to create and save journals

Comment: Some helpful reading if you have not seen this one as yet https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591887/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi but in my case , can you show me why putting save method in the journal class can result in many changes after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encapsulation**

By moving the code for persistence into a separate `PersistenceManager` class, you guarantee that the `SaveToDisk()` method will not modify any of the private variables of a journal, except by using the public methods and properties of the journal.

**Single Responsibility**

> But why can't I keep the SaveToDisk() method in Journal class? If there is any new requirements such as Save the Journal to cloud, then I just add a new method SaveToCloud(), and any dependent client classes can use SaveToCloud(), the only modification I need to make is adding SaveToCloud() in Journal class, which is totally fine?

Saving the journal to the cloud will require you to maintain some extra state - a connection string, an api key, maybe a blob client, etc. Where do you get that state?

- You could store it all as static members within the `Journal` class
- You could pass it all in to the `SaveToCloud()` method as parameters

Storing it as static members is rather limiting, and you can run in to concurrency issues.

Passing the parameters in to the `SaveToCloud()` method every time means you need to go through every class that originally called `SaveToDisk()`, and update it to store the parameters you need. These are the 'lots of tiny changes' that you want to avoid.

If instead, you made a `PersistenceManager` class, with a `Save()` method, then you can add the connection string etc to this class, and none of the callers need to change.

**Dependency Inversion**

> Entities must depend on abstractions not on concretions.

By implementing this as a static method in the `Journal` class, you remove the possibility for dependency inversion. Classes that want to save journals should define this as an interface:

```
public interface IPersistenceManager
{
    void Save(string name);
}
```

Notice it doesn't say `ToDisk()` on the end - the callers shouldn't care *where* the journal is being saved, as long as it *is* being saved. Then when your requirements change from storing on disk to storing in the cloud, **you don't need to make any code changes to the callers.**

Comment: I have added a new version that use DI in the post, could you please have a look to see if it is correct?

Comment: Yep, the new version you have posted demonstrates it pretty well. You are able to change the consumer from storing on disk to storing in the cloud, without having to modify the code of the consumer.

Comment: sorry for bringing up this question again. You mentioned that "Storing extra state as static members is rather limiting, and you can run in to concurrency issues." But as long as we don't modify the state in the code, just change them manually, there shouldn't be any issues? and we don't event make them static, can have  getters to access those state

Comment: Yes, it is possible to implement it that way. However, it is not made clear to the clients that they have to set a value for `ConnectionString` before they can use the static `Save()` method - the compiler won't force this, you just have to know. If instead you have that state in a `PersistenceManager` class, you can require the connection string in the constructor. Don't create static methods that require some sort of _init_ code to be run before they can be used, because chances are you'll forget to run it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The `Journal` class' job -- its single responsibility -- is to represent journals.  The problem with a method like `Journal.saveToDisk()` it that it requires work that is not part of that job, like deciding what filename to use, making sure nothing is left in a bad state if the process aborts, etc..  The `Journal` class shouldn't have to know anything about how to deal with disks.

As you recognized, this is the thin edge of a bad wedge.  Soon enough you will need a `Journal.saveToCloud()` and the `Journal` class will have to know all about networking, too.

In a situation like this, you have to separate the journal work from the disk work, so you can put the journal work in the `Journal` class and the disk work elsewhere.

A common solution would be to add `byte [] Journal.toByteArray()` that converts a journal to data that you could then save to either the disk, or the cloud, or anywhere else.  `Journal.writeToStream(Stream target)` would perform a similar function.  Either way, translating a journal into a sequence of bytes is journal-specific work that you can put in the `Journal` class.

Whether or not you need anything like a persistence manager depends on the rest of your application.